# Sending Bundle from Main Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, bundle

I've followed the google tutorial and am not getting any errors in my code, but for some reason the data in my bundle does not seem to be being sent from my Main Activity to my Fragment (my app just keeps returning "0.00").  Please help.

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
@Override
public void assignButtonBWHW1Clicked(String assignButtonBWHWClicked) {

    if (assignButtonBWHWClicked.equals(assignButtonBWHWClicked)) {

        assignFragment1 = new assignFragment1();
        buttonsGeneric = new genericBackNextFragment();

        splitItFragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
        splitItFragmentTransaction3 = splitItFragmentManager3.beginTransaction();
        splitItFragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fragment_container, assignFragment1);

        splitItFragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fragment_container_2, buttonsGeneric);
        splitItFragmentTransaction3.addToBackStack(null);

        splitItFragmentTransaction3.commit();

        Bundle bundleAssign = new Bundle();
        bundleAssign.putDouble("price1", 22);
        assignFragment1.setArguments(bundleAssign);

    }
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    assignFragment1View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assign_fragment_1, container, false);

    item1 = (TextView) assignFragment1View.findViewById(R.id.assign1_food_item_1);
    item2 = (TextView) assignFragment1View.findViewById(R.id.assign1_food_item_2);
    priceItem1 = (TextView) assignFragment1View.findViewById(R.id.assign1_price_item_1);
    priceItem2 = (TextView) assignFragment1View.findViewById(R.id.assign1_price_item_2);

    Bundle bundleAssign = this.getArguments();
    Double price1Double = bundleAssign.getDouble("priceItem1", 0.00);
    priceItem1.setText(String.valueOf(price1Double));

    return assignFragment1View;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update your `key` in the `fragment` side from `priceItem1` to `price1`.

```
Double price1Double = bundleAssign.getDouble("priceItem1", 0.00);
```

to

```
Double price1Double = bundleAssign.getDouble("price1", 0.00);
```

To make things clear.this happens because you are using seperate keys while adding data to bundle and retrieving using a different key. so it is returning `default value` i.e `0.00` for that `priceItem1` key

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it. It's amazing how you can review your own code a hundred times and not spot something so obvious.

Comment: Great it fixed , accept it if it helped :) so it clears from the unanwered questions queue :)

Answer (score 1):

Two change you will have to do it in your code.
first one is set the argument before transaction

```
if (assignButtonBWHWClicked.equals(assignButtonBWHWClicked)) {

        assignFragment1 = new assignFragment1();
        Bundle bundleAssign = new Bundle();
        bundleAssign.putDouble("price1", 22);
        assignFragment1.setArguments(bundleAssign);
        buttonsGeneric = new genericBackNextFragment();

        splitItFragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
        splitItFragmentTransaction3 = splitItFragmentManager3.beginTransaction();
        splitItFragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fragment_container, assignFragment1);

        splitItFragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fragment_container_2, buttonsGeneric);
        splitItFragmentTransaction3.addToBackStack(null);

        splitItFragmentTransaction3.commit();



    }
```

and second one always use same key to set and retrieve data within your bundle so change in fragment

```
  Double price1Double = bundleAssign.getDouble("priceItem1", 0.00);
```

to

```
  Double price1Double = bundleAssign.getDouble("price1", 0.00);
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much. In my case I wasn't calling the `assignFragment1.setArguments(bundleAssign);` (just a note: make that bold in your answer as this is the main difference between your answer and any other naswer on the net). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Bundle bundleAssign = getArguments();
```

Or,
`Bundle bundleAssign = getActivity().getArguments()`

Instead of

```
Bundle bundleAssign = this.getArguments();
```

Get Value like

```
double result = bundleAssign.getDouble("price1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place bundle initialisation to fragment before you get fragment nmanager.

```
if (assignButtonBWHWClicked.equals(assignButtonBWHWClicked)) {

    assignFragment1 = new assignFragment1();
    buttonsGeneric = new genericBackNextFragment();

    Bundle bundleAssign = new Bundle();
    bundleAssign.putDouble("price1", 22);
    assignFragment1.setArguments(bundleAssign);

    splitItFragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
    splitItFragmentTransaction3 = splitItFragmentManager3.beginTransaction();
    splitItFragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fragment_container, assignFragment1);

    splitItFragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fragment_container_2, buttonsGeneric);
    splitItFragmentTransaction3.addToBackStack(null);

    splitItFragmentTransaction3.commit();

}
```